# g isn't periodic

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, with the derivative continuous, so $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f'(x)=\infty.$$

Prove that $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=\sin f(x)$ isn't periodic.

Comment: Sorry, the Do-My-Homework service is closed for the weekend. Check back next Monday.

Comment: @uniquesolution I had a good laugh! On a more serious note, what did you try LLL? Where are you stuck? What theorems you think you might use?

Comment: I tried using Mean Theorems

Comment: @uniquesolution snark is unproductive, especially when new people have no idea how the site works.

Comment: @LLL, welcome to Math.SE! Please update your question with what you have tried and some thoughts on how to approach this problem, and we will be happy to guide you. In particular, you mention Mean Theorems -- which ones specifically (the term seems unfamiliar to me) and how did you apply it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What can you say about the intervals between values where, say, $g(x) = 0$?

EDIT:
Further hint: if $f'(t) \ge M$ for all $t > N$, and $N < x < y$ with $f(x) = n \pi$ and $f(y) = (n+1)\pi$, what does the Mean Value Theorem say?

Comment: I also tried to take some intervals, but I don't know how to use the fact that f is differentiable

Comment: That fact is one of the hypotheses of the theorem you're going to use.

Comment: I don't manage to solve it this way. I don't know where I am wrong